# AIR 3.2 for Android (does it run on 2.3?)

Tags: android, flash, air

I'm working with Flash CS6 and i choose to export my file as AIR 3.2 for Android, now does this work for Android version 2.3? My phone is 2.3.5 and i placed my swf file onto my phone and it cant play it... did i do anything wrong? Also i did use the file>export movie option

Canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work for those versions: [Tech Specs](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tech-specs.html)

You shouldn't be using a SWF. When you hit publish, you should get a compiled APK file. There are options under publish settings.

Watch [this video](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=131) for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

its ok, i just changed some of the settings and not all of them, so it was still making a swf and not an apk file.